# How to set NGINX to url mask a CNAME record

Tags: nginx, dns, cname

I am migrating some infrastructure and I am having the following issue.

I got a CNAME record from `api.oldserver.com` to `api.newserver.com`. I am using a multi-domain ssl with Nginx. And it all works great! 
*nginx config below

The issue is that whenever someone navigates to `api.oldserver.com` it shows at the url bar that the user is actually seeing `api.newserver.com`. I wish the user could still see the `api.olderserver.com`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri; 
} 
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  api.newerserver.com;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/domain.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/domain.key";
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of the redirect. Consider creating another server statement with the api.oldserver.com that would have the appropriate cert and would have the same proxy setup so it would be handled the same way.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri; 
} 
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  api.newerserver.com;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/domain.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/domain.key";
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  api.oldserver.com;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/nginx/olddomain.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/nginx/olddomain.key";
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Or something like that...